# Person in distress near Mulbrydale (Velen): the master swordsmith refuses to move or talk after being freed from his cage

Tags: the-witcher-3

I've freed a master swordsmith from his cage in a "Person in distress" area, near Mulbrydale, but he doesn't move and I cannot talk to him (I'm not even prompted with the "<kbd>E</kbd> Talk" tooltip).

[image: Stuck master swordsmith in Velen, near Mulbrydale]

I've tried everything I could think of: look for a quest that would be necessary to talk to him, close/open the door, look around for a last pirate that should be killed, meditate, reload, restart the game, etc.
Also when I leave and come back to the Velen area, this red glowing unsent letter (that I already had in inventory btw) appears on the floor,but it doesn't unlock anything.

[image: Red glowing unsent letter, near Mulbrydale]

Did I miss something, or is it a bug and I'll never be able to talk to him ?

Note: I'm currently playing on version 1.11, on GOG Galaxy.

Comment: Usually those people, after being rescued, will show up in a town nearby.  You don't get the reward from them right away after rescuing.

Comment: Yeah but they at least move out of the cell and say something; here there's nothing, the guy just stays there.  Also I looked everywhere around for a last pirate that would have fled, but found no one.

Comment: have you tried leaving (fast travel out of velen) and coming back?

Comment: I did, same result.

Comment: looks like he's glitched then :/

Comment: Wasn't this a known glitch for one of the shopkeeper rescues? I broke it in my last playthrough and wouldn't be surprised if this was the same.

Comment: If I leave and come back to Velen, [this red glowing unsent letter](http://i.imgur.com/JfIMwJK.jpg) (that I already had in inventory btw) appears on the floor,but it doesn't unlock anything.

Comment: @Anto had that bug too and had to load an older savegame to get this working. The bug was caused by npc stucked in wall/ground so I was unable to find and kill him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote to CD Projekt and they confirm it's a bug:

> Hello,
>
> I'm sorry about the issue that you encountered and thank you for the
>   feedback. We are aware of it and our development team is working on
>   the fix.
>
> Regards, Grzegorz

---

It's been fixed in patch 1.12.  If you cleared the area and opened the gate already, just go to Mulbrydale where the swordsmith is waiting for you.

Comment: Looks like it may be fixed in the 1.12 patch.